# How to use `perldoc` within Emacs (shell)?

Tags: perl, emacs, window

While programming using Emacs, you frequently consult manual pages.
My environment is text-based Emacs via SSH.

While I can open "Normal" manual pages in Emacs using the `man` command (`(man MAN-ARGS)`function), I wonder how to use `perldoc` for Perl POD documentation from within Emacs:
When I run it (e.g.: `perldoc -f pack`) from a `shell` (`(shell &optional BUFFER)` function), I get a message saying:

> WARNING: terminal is not fully functional

Specifically, the number of terminal lines is less than what the Emacs windows offers.
The terminal seems to be set to `dumb`, but even when I use `TERM=emacs perldoc -f pack` only 24 lines are used, and I see a `lines 1-23` prompt (pager asking to continue).
I also see that `LINES` is set to 24, even though my (outer) terminal has 103 lines.

Obviously, as the window can be resized, counting the number of lines and setting `LINES` accordingly does not look like a smart answer for this problem.
Despite of that, using `TERM=emacs LINES=100 perldoc -f pack` still stopped output at line 24.

So maybe it's an [Emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/) question, actually.

Comment: Not an answer, but have you considered using `tmux` or `screen` so you can have one pane with emacs open and another with a regular shell?

Comment: Also, you can run `man perlfunc` in emacs, then search for `pack T` (for "pack TEMPLATE") which takes you to the relevant entry. Is that a good enough workaround?

Comment: @terdon My actual use case was to read the POD for a program I'm developing, and the POD is inside the program that is just in the working directory. So `man perlfunc` does not actually help.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the solution is rather simple:
Just add `perldoc`'s `-T` option ("*This specifies that the output is not to be sent to a pager, but is to be sent directly to STDOUT.*"):

```sh
v04:~/src/Perl/OTP> perldoc -T -f pack
perldoc -T -f pack
    pack TEMPLATE,LIST
            Takes a LIST of values and converts it into a string using the
            rules given by the TEMPLATE. The resulting string is the
            concatenation of the converted values. Typically, each converted
            value looks like its machine-level representation. For example,
            on 32-bit machines an integer may be represented by a sequence
            of 4 bytes, which will in Perl be presented as a string that's 4
            characters long.
...
                # pack little-endian 16- and 32-bit signed integers
                $foo = pack('(sl)<', -42, 4711);
                # exactly the same

            The same template may generally also be used in unpack().

v04:~/src/Perl/OTP>
```